# How can i prevent my batch file from showing Path?

Tags: batch-file, path

[How can i prevent it from showing C:/Users/[Username]/Desktop/ ? [Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0cCAE.jpg)

My code:

```
@Echo off
title Menu
color A
echo You can do anything,but please don't delete system32!
echo color (1-11) title (name)
echo If you type CLS you can hide the hints!
echo For Game and Program codes type in: Codes!
cmd /k
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [prompt](http://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html), for example:

- `cmd /k prompt $$` changes the prompt to `$`
- `cmd /k prompt $T$G$S` changes the prompt to `17:29:12,44>` (with space at the end)

See more formatting codes by running `prompt /?` in the Command Prompt console.